# Programming Python vowel counter

Tags: python

I am currently using this code for my program, but I need the program to stop when the user doesn't enter an input. Except I do not know how to do that. Please help. Thankyou!

```
line = input("Enter a word:  ")

vowels = 0

for word in line:
    if word == 'a':
        vowels += 1 #more than or equal to 1
    if word == 'e':
        vowels += 1
    if word == 'i':
        vowels += 1
    if word == 'o':
        vowels += 1
    if word == 'u':
        vowels += 1

print (line, "contains", vowels, "vowels ." )
```

Comment: `if not word: sys.exit(0)`?

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest this:

```
import sys

line = input("enter a word: ").strip()
if not line:
    sys.exit(0)
vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
numVowels = 0
for char in line:
    if char in vowels:
        numVowels += 1
print(line, "contains", numVowels, "vowels." )
```

Here's a more terse version:

```
import sys

line = input("enter a word: ").strip()
if not line:
    sys.exit(0)
vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
numVowels = sum(1 for char in line if char in vowels)
print(line, "contains", numVowels, "vowels." )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    line = raw_input('enter a word: ')
    if not line:
        break
    vowels = 0
    for word in line:
        if word == 'a':
            vowels += 1
        if word == 'e':
            vowels += 1
    print (line, 'contains', vowels, 'vowels.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

vowel = set('aeiou')
while True:
    line = input("enter a word: ")
    if not line.strip():
        break
    else:
        count = len([x for x in line if x in vowel])
        print('%s: contains: %d vowels' % (line, count))
print('Exiting.')
```

output:

```
[what_you_got]:[~/script/python]:$ python f.py
enter a word: oh my god
oh my god: contains: 2 vowels
enter a word: really are u kidding me
really are u kidding me: contains: 8 vowels
enter a word:
Exiting.
[what_you_got]:[~/script/python]:$
```